# проблема с переходом на веб-страницу openVAS

Tags: linux

Xотел воспользоваться openVAS, вбиваю в поисковую строку тот самый адрес https://127.0.0.1:9392/ , но на всех браузерах мне просто выдает ошибку, но никак не связанную с безопасностью, чтобы мол "Подтвердите, что вы соглашаетесь  на риск и переходите", как я видел на всех ютуб-туториалах.

А вот что выводится:

```
При соединении с 127.0.0.1:9392 произошла ошибка.

Возможно, сайт временно недоступен или перегружен запросами. Подождите некоторое время и попробуйте снова.
Если вы не можете загрузить ни одну страницу – проверьте настройки соединения с Интернетом.
Если ваш компьютер или сеть защищены межсетевым экраном или прокси-сервером – убедитесь, что Firefox разрешён выход в Интернет.

ПОПРОБОВАТЬ СНОВА 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Собственно, я просто не понимаю что с этим делать и куда двигаться. (Пробовал на 4х браузерах, 2 дня)
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что вместо ошибки должно быть что-то другое? Что вы для этого предприняли?

Comment: Ничего не предпринимал, потому что и не было сказано предпринимать. Видео: https://youtu.be/yCeM1gBpOFY?si=EMSVgEW1EwABhxdD [10:47] . человек просто вбил адрес и у него все появилось.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас возникли проблемы при установке OpenVas,если вы устанавливали его вручную.
Воспользуйтесь контейнером для установки OpenVas и повторите свои дейсвия.
Контейнер:
https://itsecforu.ru/2019/09/09/%F0%9F%90%B3-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-openvas-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-docker-%D0%B2-ubuntu/
Описание:
https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/22.4/container/index.html